# How to sign with a specific subkey using GnuPG?

Tags: gnupg, digital-signature

Say I have two subkeys like below.

```
/c/Users/user/.gnupg/secring.gpg
---------------------------------
sec   2048R/DC****** 2017-05-25
uid                  J D <J.D@gmail.com>
ssb   2048R/B69A1297 2017-05-25
ssb   2048R/BA3177DC 2018-06-08
```

Both of the subkeys can be used to sign a message. How can I sign my message with the subkey **BA3177DC**?

Comment: Try adding "!" after the keyid you specify : `gpg -u BA3177DC! --sign .....`